# IPython in Emacs. Quick code evaluation

Tags: python, shell, emacs, ipython

**Update**: The question still lacks a satisfactory answer.

I would like to "send" code snippets to a IPython interpreter in Emacs 23.2 (Linux). Assuming that I have already started an IPython shell in a buffer in Emacs (e.g. using `Python-mode.el` and `IPython.el`), is there a way of selecting a region in a different buffer and "sending" this region to the already-started IPython shell?

I have tried `C-c C-c` (send-buffer-to-shell) and `C-c |` (send-region-to-shell), but **this only works as long as the code is written in Python and not in IPython** (IPython can run Python code). The reason seems to be that, for both commands, Emacs creates a temporary file with `.py` extension (as opposed to with `.ipy` extension), which then is interpreted by IPython as "Python-specific code". This prevents me from using IPython-specific features 
such as magic commands.

On a separate note, I have also read that Emacs provides `M-| ('shell-command-on-region')` to run selected regions in a shell. To do this with an IPython interpreter, I have tried setting `shell-file-name` to my IPython path. However, when I run `M-|` after selecting a region, Emacs prompts me the following:

> Shell command on region:

and if I then type `RET`, I get the IPython man page on the `*Shell Command Output*` buffer, without the region being executed. Is there any IPython-specific command that I can use for `M-| ('shell-command-on-region')` to get IPython run my code?

Thanks!

Comment: Assuming you can run ipython directly, I suspect you actually want to leave `shell-file-name` alone, and simply enter the ipython executable name at the prompt. That's the normal usage for `shell-command-on-region`, at any rate. The minibuffer history will remember that command, so you can easily repeat it with `M-| M-p RET`. I'm not sure how `call-process-region` works, but I imagine it sends the region text to the command as stdin, so as long as the ipython command can deal with receiving a script that way, I would think it ought to work (although if not, it might account for the help text).

Comment: Thank you phils, that solution works, but it requires opening starting a new IPython shell (which takes some time to start) every time I need to test a code snippet

Answer (score 1):

Are you using ipython.el?
It should work okay with Emacs 23.

If not, have a look at [EmacsWiki: iPython Emacs 23](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/PythonProgrammingInEmacs#toc10).

There is also a section in the IPython Cookbook on Emacs (search for IPythonEmacs23; sorry am not allowed to post more than one link :(

Once you've started an ipython-shell (C-c !) you can execute code snippets from regions of any buffer in this already started shell using "Execute region ("C-c |")

Andreas

Comment: Thanks Andreas. I am already using IPython.el The EmacsWiki site is a bit confusing though. Have you succeeded in sending IPython-specific code snippets to an already-open IPython shell in Emacs?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand your question, but once I've started an ipython-shell (C-c !) I can execute code snippets from regions of any buffer in this already started shell using "Execute region ("C-c |")

Comment: Added my last comment to the answer

Comment: Andreas. `"Execute region" (C-c |)` only works for me when the code snippet is written in Python and has no IPython-specific features.

For example, I can't send to the shell code snippets with IPython magic commands such as `!bash_command`. The reason seems to be that Emacs creates a temporary file with the `.py` extension (as opposed to with the `.ipy` extension)

Comment: Oopss...missed the "ipython specific" bit.

Answer (score 0):

I found a partial answer to **Q1**:

Python-mode provides `C-c C-c` which can send a buffer to an already-opened Python shell (similarly `C-c C-|` can send a region to the shell), and if `ipython.el` is installed, then default python shell is set to IPython.

Unfortunately, this only works for python scripts, and not for IPython scripts. `C-c C-c` works by copying the buffer with the code snippet to a temporary file with extension **.py** that is then sent to the shell. Since the file has extension **.py** IPython executes it as if it was regular Python code, and therefore the code snippet cannot have IPython-specific code (such as IPython magic commands)..